# Iterate pyarrow._flight.FlightStreamReader

Tags: python, pyarrow, dremio

How do I iterate through a `reader`, assuming its a `pyarrow._flight.FlightStreamReader` object.
Which can be obtained from

```
reader = client.do_get(flight_info.endpoints[0].ticket, options)
```

Entire `example.py` script came from https://github.com/dremio-hub/arrow-flight-client-examples/blob/main/python/example.py

Currently I try `reader.read_pandas()` so that it will generate a dataframe for the entire Dremio results.  Unfortunately, if the query has over 50 million rows or so, it may not fit to the dataframe/or may not have enough memory for it, and my process just gets killed.  How do I iterate through the reader object and just get chunks so I can maybe generate dataframe per chunk.

When I use

```
for chunk in reader.read_chunk():
    print(chunk.to_pandas())
```

for the first chunk, it will convert/extract only 3968 rows from the results and put it in a dataframe, but for the second chunk its a `None` object.  My example really has a millions rows.

In short how can I iterate through the reader per specified chunk size?  And is it possible to print these chunks per rows without converting it to a dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following and it works great

```
while True:
 try:
  batch, buf = reader.read_chunk()
  yield batch
 except StopIteration:
  break
```

The cunsumer function doing the batch.to_pandas()

The missing part is how to configure the chunk size